# Why use the key parameter when calling AddComponent on WindsorContainer?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

The AddComponent method on the IWindsorContainer interface has several overloads, for example:

```
WindsorContainer.AddComponent<I,T>()
```

and

```
WindsorContainer.AddComponent<I,T>(string key)
```

What's the use of the key parameter and why should I use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the key parameter if you were registered multiple implementations of the same interface.  That way you can later retrieve a specific one.  For example, I may have multiple versions of IHandler.

```
container.AddComponent<IHandler, FileHandler>("handlers.file");
container.AddComponent<IHandler, HttpHandler>("handlers.http");
//I can retrieve the first one like this (or something like this).
IHandler fileHandler = container.Resolve<IHandler>();
//I can retrieve the http handler like this 
IHandler httpHandler = container.Resolve<IHandler>("handlers.http");
```

In addition, when you register a component without a key, I believe it's type is used as the key.

```
container.AddComponent<IHandler, FileHandler>();
```

I believe this is registered with a key of "{Namespace}.IHandler". So it could actually be retrieved later using the automatic key as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it somewhere in the documentation.

About halfway [on this page](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/usingmicrokernel.html) they say

> Please note that more than one implementation for the same service can be added. In this case, when you request a component by the service, the first component registered for that service will be returned. To obtain the other implementations for the same service you must use the key.